# Converting from EST to EDT in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I have a date which is in `EST` timezone. I need to convert it to `EDT` using Java 8.

I tried `DateFormat.setTimeZone` but didn't work. Please note my local server is in `EDT` time.

```
DateFormat edtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm zzz");

edtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

return edtFormat.format(date).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Your server is not in EDT.  It's in Eastern time, which *alternates* between EST and EDT.  Use `"America/New_York"` in Java.